# Using FileChooser to open user file path and filter by extensions

Tags: java, user-interface, filechooser

I am new to GUI coding in Java. My program needs to accept a file path entered by the user via a JTextField. The user can then select one of four JCheckBoxes that correlate to a certain file extension filter. When the user presses a button, the file is opened at the specified path.

Question 1) : Have I correctly coded for each of the filter types that I want?

Question 2) : How can I directly open a file from the location entered by the user using JFileChooser?

I have searched various forums that discuss the use of one file extension filter, but not multiple filters at once via CheckBox selection. I know how to open a generic FileChooser panel and select files. I really just need some help in determining the best layout for this program to work, and perhaps a more detailed example of the use of JFileChooser that is relevant to my scenario.

```
public class FinderPanel extends JPanel{

private JButton fileButton;
private JTextField fileText;
private JCheckBox jpg,bmp,txt,doc;
private JFileChooser chooser;

public FinderPanel(){

    fileButton=new JButton("open file");
    fileButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    fileText=new JTextField(10); // file path is entered in textfield
    fileText.setToolTipText("Enter file path here.");

    jpg=new JCheckBox(".jpg");
    jpg.setForeground(Color.green);
    bmp=new JCheckBox(".bmp");
    bmp.setForeground(Color.green);
    txt=new JCheckBox(".txt");
    txt.setForeground(Color.green);
    doc=new JCheckBox(".doc");
    doc.setForeground(Color.green);

    CheckBoxListener check=new CheckBoxListener();
    jpg.addItemListener(check);
    bmp.addItemListener(check);
    txt.addItemListener(check);
    doc.addItemListener(check);

    add(fileText);
    add(fileButton);
    add(jpg);
    add(bmp);
    add(txt);
    add(doc);

    setBackground(Color.black);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200)); 
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        // search for a given file based on input path and selected filters

        // file is opened at path
    }
}
private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        chooser=new JFileChooser();

        if(jpg.isSelected()){
            FileFilter jpg=new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg","jpeg");
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(jpg);
        }
        if(bmp.isSelected()){
            FileFilter bmp=new FileNameExtensionFilter("bmp");
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(bmp);
        }
        if(txt.isSelected()){
            FileFilter txt=new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt","text");
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(txt);
        }
        if(doc.isSelected()){
            FileFilter doc=new FileNameExtensionFilter("doc");
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Question 1) : Have I correctly coded for each of the filter types that I want?"* - That's a debug operation that you should be performing

Comment: *"Question 2) : How can I directly open a file from the location entered by the user using JFileChooser?"* - Do you mean you want the file chooser to open, browsing that location, or you want to get the file selected file by the user from the `JFileChooser`?

Comment: I "think" you want to have a look at [`JFileChooser#setCurrentDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory-java.io.File-)

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd want to go through the hassle.  Just seed the `JFileChooser` with all the options, open it and let the user go about their business.  If you wanted to, you could "save" the last known location and filter the user used

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm wording my request clearly. As I understand, `JFileChooser` allows a user to browse files and select one to open. I need to implement `JFileChooser` to open a file directly given a specific file path.

Comment: Have you read the [How to use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) tutorial yet?

Comment: *" I need to implement JFileChooser to open a file directly given a specific file path"* seems counterintuitive. If you already know the file, why do you ned the `JFileChooser`?  If you want to allow the user to browser from a specific directory, then, as I said, you probably want `JFileChooser#setCurrentDirectory` - this will set the starting position. You can't otherwise restrict them, they could browse to a different location, which is kind of my point. Why not just open the chooser and let the user browser to the location, select the filters they need and find the file they want?

Comment: I understand what you mean @MadProgrammer, and it does seem odd. My assignment specified to "implement the application that opens file chooser at a given location." I'm beginning to think that I may have misinterpreted the goal of the program. I will try a new approach and update my progress.

Comment: @VGR I will read over the tutorial in tandem with the assignment to get a better sense of what I need to do.

Comment: *"implement the application that opens file chooser at a given location."* - `JFileChooser#setCurrentDirectory`